# Drawing links that do not affect the physics of a force directed graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I need to draw some links between nodes in a force directed graph but I would like those links to not affect the physics of the graph. There are other existing links that *do* affect the physics.

In the attached example, I would like to draw the links defined as "links2" but have them just "follow" the layout of the rest of the graph. I would like those lines to be animated as part of the simulation but not influence the final graph.

I have manually drawn what I would like the final result to look like.

[image: Manually drawn desired result]

I don't know how to separately reference the nodes that are part of the force layout.

```js
  var nodes = [
    { name: "node0" },
    { name: "node1" },
    { name: "node2" },
    { name: "node3" },
    { name: "node4" },
    { name: "node5" },
    { name: "node6" },
    { name: "node7" },
    { name: "node8" },
    { name: "node9" },
    { name: "node10" },
    { name: "node11" },
    { name: "node12" },
    { name: "node13" },
    { name: "node14" },
    { name: "node15" },
    { name: "node16" },
    { name: "node17" },
    { name: "node18" },
    { name: "node19" }
  ];

  var links = [
    { source: 0, target: 9 },
    { source: 1, target: 9 },
    { source: 2, target: 9 },
    { source: 3, target: 9 },
    { source: 4, target: 9 },
    { source: 5, target: 9 },
    { source: 6, target: 9 },
    { source: 7, target: 9 },
    { source: 8, target: 9 },
    { source: 10, target: 19 },
    { source: 11, target: 19 },
    { source: 12, target: 19 },
    { source: 13, target: 19 },
    { source: 14, target: 19 },
    { source: 15, target: 19 },
    { source: 16, target: 19 },
    { source: 17, target: 19 },
    { source: 18, target: 19 }
  ];

var links2 = [
    { source: 0, target: 10 },
    { source: 1, target: 11 },
    { source: 2, target: 12 },
    { source: 3, target: 13 }
]
  
  var width = 700;
  var height = 300;

  var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(nodes)
    .links(links)
    .size([width, height])
    .linkDistance(50)
    .charge(-700)
    .on("tick", tick)
    .start();

  var svg = d3.select("#graph").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

  var colors = d3.scale.category10();

  var line = svg.append("g").selectAll("line")
    .data(force.links())
    .enter().append("line")
    .attr('class', 'link')
    .attr('stroke', function(d, i) {
      return colors(i);
    })

  var circle = svg.append("g").selectAll("circle")
    .data(force.nodes())
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 8)
    .attr('class', 'circle')
    .attr('fill', function(d, i) {
      return colors(i);
    })
    .call(force.drag);

  var text = svg.append("g").selectAll("text")
    .data(force.nodes())
    .enter().append("text")
    .attr("x", 14)
    .attr("y", ".31em")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.name;
    });

  function tick() {
    line.attr({
      x1: function(d) {
        return d.source.x;
      },
      y1: function(d) {
        return d.source.y;
      },
      x2: function(d) {
        return d.target.x;
      },
      y2: function(d) {
        return d.target.y;
      }
    });
    circle.attr("transform", transform);
    text.attr("transform", transform);
  }

  function transform(d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
  }
```

```css
  .link {
    fill: none;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
  }
  
  circle {
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
  }
  
  text {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
  
  #graph {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
  <div id="root">
    <div style="background-color:lightgrey" id="graph" height="800px" width="800px">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Any assistance much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your link2 reference the nodes by index, so in the tick use that to index in the nodes array. And it is better to use classes for the different types of links and nodes.

The links that are not force related have a dash pattern.

```js
var nodes = [
  { name: "node0" },
  { name: "node1" },
  { name: "node2" },
  { name: "node3" },
  { name: "node4" },
  { name: "node5" },
  { name: "node6" },
  { name: "node7" },
  { name: "node8" },
  { name: "node9" },
  { name: "node10" },
  { name: "node11" },
  { name: "node12" },
  { name: "node13" },
  { name: "node14" },
  { name: "node15" },
  { name: "node16" },
  { name: "node17" },
  { name: "node18" },
  { name: "node19" }
];

var links = [
  { source: 0, target: 9 },
  { source: 1, target: 9 },
  { source: 2, target: 9 },
  { source: 3, target: 9 },
  { source: 4, target: 9 },
  { source: 5, target: 9 },
  { source: 6, target: 9 },
  { source: 7, target: 9 },
  { source: 8, target: 9 },
  { source: 10, target: 19 },
  { source: 11, target: 19 },
  { source: 12, target: 19 },
  { source: 13, target: 19 },
  { source: 14, target: 19 },
  { source: 15, target: 19 },
  { source: 16, target: 19 },
  { source: 17, target: 19 },
  { source: 18, target: 19 }
];

var links2 = [
    { source: 0, target: 10 },
    { source: 1, target: 11 },
    { source: 2, target: 12 },
    { source: 3, target: 13 }
]

var width = 700;
var height = 300;

var force = d3.layout.force()
  .nodes(nodes)
  .links(links)
  .size([width, height])
  .linkDistance(50)
  .charge(-700)
  .on("tick", tick)
  .start();

var svg = d3.select("#graph").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

var colors = d3.scale.category10();

var line = svg.append("g").selectAll(".link")
  .data(force.links())
  .enter().append("line")
  .attr('class', 'link')
  .attr('stroke', function(d, i) { return colors(i); });

var line2 = svg.append("g").selectAll(".link2")
  .data(links2)
  .enter().append("line")
  .attr('class', 'link2')
  .attr('stroke-dasharray', '5,5')
  .attr('stroke', function(d, i) { return colors(i); });

var circle = svg.append("g").selectAll(".circle")
  .data(force.nodes())
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("r", 8)
  .attr('class', 'circle')
  .attr('fill', function(d, i) {
    return colors(i);
  })
  .call(force.drag);

var text = svg.append("g").selectAll("text")
  .data(force.nodes())
  .enter().append("text")
  .attr("x", 14)
  .attr("y", ".31em")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.name;
  });

function tick() {
  line.attr({
    x1: function(d) { return d.source.x; },
    y1: function(d) { return d.source.y; },
    x2: function(d) { return d.target.x; },
    y2: function(d) { return d.target.y; }
  });
  line2.attr({
    x1: function(d) { return nodes[d.source].x; },
    y1: function(d) { return nodes[d.source].y; },
    x2: function(d) { return nodes[d.target].x; },
    y2: function(d) { return nodes[d.target].y; }
  });
  circle.attr("transform", transform);
  text.attr("transform", transform);
}

function transform(d) {
  return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
}
```

```css
.link {
    fill: none;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
  }
  
  circle {
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
  }
  
  text {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
  
  #graph {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
  <div id="root">
    <div style="background-color:lightgrey" id="graph" height="800px" width="800px">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```